# Angular 4 *ngFor array length with pipe

Tags: angular

I have a range slider in my app. If you drag the range slider, based on "sliderPipe" change results will appear. My problem is I'm unable to display the "No Records Found" message.

#### html template

```
<div class="well" *ngFor="let data of onewayFormData$ | 
                                  sliderPipe: sliderValue as results;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 onewayresults">
      <h2> {{ data.cost | currency: 'INR':true }} </h2>
      <h3> {{ data.agencycode }} </h3>
      <h5> {{ data.ocity }} > {{ data.dcity }}</h5>
      <h5> Depart: {{ data.depart }} </h5>
      <h5> Arrive: {{ data.arrive }} </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div style="float:right;">
        <img [src]="data.imageurl" width="120px" height="100px" [alt]="data.agency" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-success"> Book Tickets </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  Length: {{ results }}
  <div class="well" *ngIf="results.length == ''">
    <div class="alert alert-danger"> No Results Found....... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Pipe Code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sliderPipe'
})
export class SliderPipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args ? ) { // ES6 array destructuring
  console.log('Arguments: ' , value.length);
  return value.filter(data => {
      return data.cost >= args;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you just experimenting with the formatting options of Markdown, or do you have an actual question? Please review [ask] and the other material in the [help].

Comment: I tried very hard for posting the question

Comment: I reformatted your question, please check if its content is still valid.

Comment: It's perfect now. Thanks and i need solution also?

Comment: Also, it would be good, if you tried to make your example smaller. That makes it easier for others to help you. Check the SO guide about MCVE for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If `results` is an array:

The length of an array is always of type `number`, so you need to check against `results.length == 0` for an empty array.

If `results` is of type number:

Check against `results == 0`.

Comment: <div *ngIf="results.length === 0"> No records Found... </div> I need like this. but it's not working. I tried results.length < 0 also not working.

Comment: slider: <input type="range" min="0" max="30000" [(ngModel)]="sliderValue" />